# interactive SMTP command using telnet via a shell script

Tags: shell-script, smtp, telnet, interactive

I'm trying to access a SMTP remote server thru a remote shell using telnet and a command file `command.txt` containing command to send to that SMTP server as seen on https://tecadmin.net/ways-to-send-email-from-linux-command-line/# (note: that on the above website this is done interactivly) but here I want to do that inside a command file (I've just copied the yellow/red (the user input)) to the command file.

```
HELO yahoo.com
mail from: sender@tecadmin.net
rcpt to: myemail@mail.com
data

Hey
This is test email only

Thanks
.

quit
```

then using `telnet IP smtp < command.txt` always returns:

```
Trying 1.1.65.49...
Connected to 1.1.65.49.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

whereas when I do it interactily with:

```
perlhook@bbis:~/temp_25$ telnet 1.1.65.49 smtp
Trying 1.1.65.49...
Connected to 1.1.65.49.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 miraino-manabi.jp ESMTP Postfix
HELO yahoo.com
250 miraino-manabi.jp
mail from: sender@tecadmin.net
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: myemail@ymail.com
554 5.7.1 <myemail@ymail.com>: Relay access denied
^]
telnet> quit
```

I get a return codes `220 250 554`.

I'v also tried inside a here-doc shell script as following:

```
telnet 1.1.65.49 smtp <<END_SCRIPT
HELO yahoo.com
mail from: sender@tecadmin.net
rcpt to: myemail@mail.com
data

Hey
This is test email only

Thanks
.

quit
END_SCRIPT
```

and get the same results.

How can I get around this and make the script act as is it was interactive?

Answer (score 5):

`telnet` fails for a variety of reasons. First up, if you `strace` it the relevant errors are `telnet` wanting a TTY on standard input, of which there is none (because of the redirect) so `telnet` fails.

```
$ strace telnet mx.example.edu 25 < input
...
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B0 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

If instead `nc` or `netcat` is used, the non-interactive send may still be a problem; either too much is sent in one go (which will confuse the remote server) or the server will object to too much data too quickly; SMTP is an interactive conversation. If one side is blasting away the other may delay or reject that (sending too quickly can be an indication of a spammer). If your `nc` supports `--delay` and the remote mail server is forgiving you *may* be able to to send.

```
$ strace -s 80 nc --crlf --delay 1 mx.example.edu 25 < input
...
recvfrom(3, "220 mx.example.edu ESMTP OpenSMTPD\r\n", 8192, ...
...
sendto(3, "HELO client.example.edu\r\nmail from: jhqdoe@client.example.edu\r\n...
...
shutdown(3, SHUT_WR)                    = 0
...
recvfrom(3, "500 5.5.1 Invalid command: Pipelining not supported\r\n",
```

OpenSMTPD here rejects the send; Postfix on a different server (not shown here) allows the above send.

A SMTP client that speaks the SMTP protocol really should be used instead; this could be kludged together with something like `expect` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320592/telnet-smtp-with-expect-or-shell-script or otherwise there are various SMTP libraries in various languages that will support TLS, SMTP AUTH, handle errors, and so forth. The shell is not a good choice here...unless you use the TCP features of a shell like ZSH, but there's probably better things to do than to "not invented here" yet another SMTP client...